# SharePoint 2013 forcing Excel client to close/re-open

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel

One of our users is experiencing an issue whereby opening an Excel file from a SharePoint 2013 library causes the client-program to close and reopen, loosing any previously open files (i.e. if Excel is already open, and there are other Excel files open, then opening another Excel file from SharePoint forces Excel to close and reopen, loosing the other open files).

Anyone come across anything like this before?

Comment: I've a similar issue with Excel ver.1811. With excel 1812 instead I can't open any file. I use sharepoint 2016

Comment: This could be a version issue with Excel. What version are you using? Also, a potential work around would be to open the library with File Explorer and open from there. That may not cause the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as following:

1. What’s the version of Excel? If you use excel 2010, there is a command issue mentioned in the thread below:

   [Excel 2010 Crashes When Opening Files From Sharepoint (office 365)](https://superuser.com/questions/986693/excel-2010-crashes-when-opening-files-from-sharepoint-office-365)
2. Try to Install the latest updates and check again.
3. Repair your Office programs
4. Check to see if your antivirus software is up-to-date or conflicting with Excel

   Reference:

   [Excel not responding, hangs, freezes or stops working](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-not-responding-hangs-freezes-or-stops-working-37e7d3c9-9e84-40bf-a805-4ca6853a1ff4)